# GraphView Realtime graphing tends to be messy

Tags: android, graphing, android-graphview

I am using GraphView in android to plot realtime data. The problem with this is a lot of values are generated. So, the entire application tends to get really really slow. Is there any way I could clear the data/values that are not in the viewport? I don't really need the past values as I won't be allowing the user to scroll manually.﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Parameters:

value - the new data to append
scrollToEnd - true => graphview will scroll to the end (maxX)
maxDataCount - if max data count is reached, the oldest data value will be lost
```